# Remote authentication to an anchore server

Tags: security, authentication, containers, remote-access

I'd  like to integrate my java application with a remotely deployed [anchore-engine](https://github.com/anchore/anchore-engine) for static scanning of container images.  I have used the API Client specified [here](https://github.com/anchore/anchore-engine/blob/master/anchore_engine/services/apiext/swagger/swagger.yaml) as a guide . I still encounter authentication errors as below :

`Exception in thread "main" io.swagger.client.ApiException: Unauthorized at io.swagger.client.ApiClient.handleResponse(ApiClient.java:922)`
`at io.swagger.client.ApiClient.execute(ApiClient.java:838) at io.swagger.client.api.VulnerabilitiesApi.getImageVulnerabilitiesByTypeWithHttpInfo`
`(VulnerabilitiesApi.java:142) at o.swagger.client.api.VulnerabilitiesApi.getImageVulnerabilitiesByType(VulnerabilitiesApi.java:127)` 
`at io.cavasTest.CavasTest.main(CavasTest.java:28)`

I tried authenticating via the code below -

```
authentications = new HashMap<String, Authentication>();
authentications.put("basicAuth", new HttpBasicAuth());
HttpBasicAuth httpBasicAuth = new HttpBasicAuth();
httpBasicAuth.setUsername("xxxxx");
httpBasicAuth.setPassword("xxxxx");
```

Is there something I am missing ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've commented in the github ticket: https://github.com/anchore/anchore-engine/issues/72

I'm not very familiar with the java code that swagger generates, but based on this snipped you're adding the user and password to an HttpBasicAuth object that is not actually in the HashMap. I think this should work:

```
authentications = new HashMap<String, Authentication>();
HttpBasicAuth httpBasicAuth = new HttpBasicAuth();
httpBasicAuth.setUsername("xxxxx");
httpBasicAuth.setPassword("xxxxx");
authentications.put("basicAuth", httpBasicAuth);
```

Comment: my bad ! Authentication works now. There yet another challenge, it's better I ask another question focused on it.